# Omniscript embedded in experience site doesnt show the changes from the latest version?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, community-builder, omniscript

I am facing a issue that I spent couple of days to figure it but no luck yet. The issue is I have an omniscript thats included in an experience site and after the inclusion I have updated the omniscript with some extra fields inputs but the changes doesnt reflect on the experience site. I have tried removing it and readding it, creating a new version and adding it but the experience site still shows the previous verison. Anyone have experienced this issue or any idea on this please would appreciate that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OmniScript components are compiled to components, which are then cached by the the Digital Experience when you use the Publish feature. You need to publish your site after making changes for those changes to affect the site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already republished it but still doesnt show me the changes.